# Configurable Public DNS Service

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic

Does anyone know of a service that would allow me to create a personalized DNS server that responded differently based on what the IP of the user making the request?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. You may want to look at Bind and the view option though. You set up an ACL that matches the clients you want to access the view. For example here it is "localnets" Then you do this:

```
view "internal" {
      match-clients { localnets; };
      recursion yes;    

      zone "mydomain.com" {
           type master;
           file "mydomain.com.internal";
      };
};
```